# login failed error for my database on localnetwork

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, remote-access, local-network

I created my database on the server using code. Now no client on the local network can login to my database. This error occurs:

```
:"cannot open database "test" requested by the login.
the login failed for user "farzane".
```

Here is the connection string for my database:

```
ConnectionString=@"Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;
   Integrated security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False";
```

How can I fix this problem?

I have about 30 clients on my network, and I don't want to create a login for every one.  Is it possible to assign permissions and read/write access for all of them using code?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your clients have existing accounts on your LAN, you can right-click on the database, select Properties and then the Permissions section to assign users and groups the permissions you want them to have on your database.  Alternatively, you can go to Security/Logins and right-click the groups or users you want to assign permissions to, select Properties, then choose the User Mappings section to grant permissions on specific databases.

Because you can do it with the GUI, you must be able to do it in code, but that I am afraid is not my area of expertise.

Comment: i try this way that you said,but i do't want to assign permissons one by one for every user,can you tell me how can i active "guest" user and give it owner permission for my database?.i do it with GUI but with code i don't know.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to do it in code, although I know it can be done.  Did it work using the GUI?  If so, maybe you can post how you did it with the GUI and ask how to do the same thing in code.